# MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have the following code

**database.js file**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { MONGO_URI } = process.env;

exports.connect = () => {
    // lets connect our database

    mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,

    }).then(() =>{
        console.log('connected to the database')
    }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log('connection to the database failed');
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });

};
```

**index.js file**

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const { API_PORT } = process.env;
const port = process.env.PORT || API_PORT;



server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

when i run my index.js file i get an error

```
server is running on port 4001
connection to the database failed
MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number
```

My .env file (note:password and name is made up)

```
API_PORT=4001

MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://dwin:#12345@cluster0.3qohzms.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

what coulb be wrong with the above code?

Comment: can you please try `dwin:12345` instead of `dwin:#12345`